# How do I get it to split the tuple individually after it is converted from list

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I've tried multiple means of splitting the tuple into individual items but each time I try it returns the same `('0,1 0,2',)` output instead of `('0,1' '0,2')`. I need it to be tuple in order to match another input later in the program (which I removed for conciseness).

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
P1o=[]
P2o=[]
MAX_ROWS = MAX_COL = 10

def turn():
            tupleP1o = tuple(i for i in P1o)
            print(tupleP1o)
            tupleP2o = tuple(i for i in P2o)
            print(tupleP2o)            
def Battleship1():
    layout = [
                [sg.Text('Player1 please enter your ship positions'), sg.InputText('', size=(10,1), key='input_\P1o')],
                [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
                          ]
    window = sg.Window('player1 values', layout)
   
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == 'Submit':
            x = values['input_\P1o']
            P1o.append(x)
            window.close()
            #turn()
        elif event == 'cancel':
            window.close()
            break
    layout = [
                [sg.Text('Player2 please enter your ship positions'), sg.InputText('', size=(10,1), key='input_\P2o')],
                [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
                          ]
    window = sg.Window('player2 values', layout)
    
    while True:
        event, values = window.read() 
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == 'Submit':
            y = values['input_\P2o']
            P2o.append(y)
            window.close()
            turn()
            turn_()
        if event == 'cancel':
            window.close()
        break
```

Comment: Hello. Please provide a minimalistic code. It is very hard here to understand which tuple you are talking about.

Comment: FYI, `tuple(i for i in P1o)` can be simplified to just `tuple(P1o)`

Comment: I don't see any calls to `split()` anywhere.

Comment: What is `('0,1' '0,2')` supposed to be? Taken literally, it is just the plain string `'0,10,2'`, not a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string like `'0,1 0,2'` and want to turn it into the tuple `('0,1' '0,2')` use `str.split()` to split it at whitespace, then `tuple()` to convert that list to a tuple.

```
s = '0,1 0,2'
t = tuple(s.split())
print(t)
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and received this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: `s` is a string, not  tuple.

Answer (score 0):

*Your question needs to be clarified.*

Do you need a **tuple with a one string that is splitted by whitespace character**? Maybe you need a **tuple that contains tuples of splitted strings**?

```
some_str = ("0,1 2,3 4,5 6,7 8,9")
result = tuple([tuple(i.split(",")) for i in some_str.split()])
```

Result:

```
(('0', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('4', '5'), ('6', '7'), ('8', '9'))
```

or (as suggested by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75171055)):

```
s = '0,1 0,2'
t = tuple(s.split())
```

Result:

```
('0,1' '0,2')
```

Comment: The second one would be ideal but when tried that i received the error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'